# save JObjects in one class and use in another one(Beginner)

Tags: java, user-interface, split, textfield

I wanna know if it's possible,to save every JObjects in one class and to use in another.Something like this:

This is mainc class:

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

         public static void main(String[] args){
            new Main(); 
         }
         public Main(){
             field = new JTextField(12);
             button = new JButton("Click");
             add(field);
             add(button)   


  setTitle("main");
            getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(920, 420);
            setLocation(100, 100);
            setVisible(true);
         }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }
```

and the second Save class:

```
  // all imports
   public class Save{
      public JTextField field;
      public JButton button;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure that is possible.

```
...
     public Main(){
         Save saveObject = new Save();
         saveObject.field = new JTextField(12);
         saveObject.button = new JButton("Click");
         add(saveObject.field);
         add(saveObject.button);
         this.save = saveObject;//assuming you have a class field of type Save named "save"   
...
```

FYI

You shouldn't allow modification of the fields of the Save class directly. The common convention in OOP is to use getter and setter methods.